# Convergent by Ratio test?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am lost with this problem: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^n}{2^n n!}.$$

I am suppose to find if it is convergent or divergent.

I have the correct set up. After cancelling everything I am left with this:

$$\lim \frac{ (n+1)^{n+1} }{ 2(n+1)n^n }$$

How do I get the limit from that?

Comment: Your link has two series. Which one are you referring to?

Comment: The first one, but they are pretty much exactly the same problem.

Comment: See also [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a_n=\frac{n^n}{2^n n!}$. Then $$\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\frac{\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{2^{n+1}(n+1)!}}{\frac{n^n}{2^n n!}}=\frac{(n+1)^n}{2n^n}.$$ Evaluating the limit, we get
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n=\frac{e}{2}>1.$$
By the ratio test, this series does not converge.

Comment: That last limit is $e$, is it not?

Comment: Oh yes, good call.

Comment: Thanks.  Glad the comment helped.

Comment: Same as mine now!  ;-))

Comment: Thank you!!  Much appreciative.

Answer (score 4):

We have $a_n=\frac{n^n}{2^n\,n!}$.  Thus,

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{2^{n+1}(n+1)!}\frac{2^n\,n!}{n^n}=\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\to \frac{e}{2}>1\implies \text{the series diverges}$$

Comment: Hi, I don't understand how the function suddenly becomes 1/2(1+1/n)^n

Comment: @SaturnIndra $$\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{n+1}=(n+1)^n$$  And $$\frac{n+1}{n}=1+\frac1n$$.

Comment: Ahh thank you so much!

Comment: You're quite welcome!!  My pleasure really.